# aws cross account websocket lambda "AccessDeniedException is not authorized to access this resource"

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda

Scenario:

- I have account A, with a Websocket API - Lambda Proxy integration.
- I created a route in my Websocket API, that invokes a lambda function from account B.
- Lambda function in account B is using ApiGatewayManagementApi.postToConnection method to send data to a client connected to the Websocket API on account A.
- I get this error in CloudWatch from Lambda function on account B: "AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::BBBBBB:assumed-role/BBBBB-ROLE/BBBB-LAMBDA is not authorized to access this resource"

I don't understand why I get this error and how to determine which "resource" cannot be accessed.